# How to trigger local storage event?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to store an element's html in localStorage object so that I can retrieve it later. How can I do this? I tried

```
$(function(){
  $('window').on("storage", function (){
    localStorage.setItem("check", $('#checking').html());
  })
};
```

I want to store the html everytime the html is changed? How can I do that? Should I attach the event handler to the onchange event of the html element? 
I have multiple lists that I want to store in local storage. Should I just attach the storage event to the onchange event of the li element. 
p.s: I'm working on Firefox

Comment: What is the "storage event" ?  ,do you need do store in local storage ONLY if it is avaibale ?

Comment: This makes no sense at all to me ?

Comment: yeah store only when storage available. Storage event I don't have much idea about, Some event that stores the html on change. Is there some totally different way of doing this? I just want to save html so that on refreshing page it doesn't go away. Not storing in server side

Comment: The storage event is triggered when you change `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage. If you don't set anything to `localStorage` *outside* of the event handler, the handler will never be triggered. But it seems like the storage event is not actually what you want. This is an X&Y problem. You have a problem X and think Y is the solution and that's why you ask about Y. Please provide a better explanation of your *actual* problem (X).

Comment: @adeneo how then will the storage happen? Will it happen everytime if I register the event in document.ready?

Comment: If you want save the html page, use the cache manifest : [Using the application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

Comment: @Coderaemon - You're asking the wrong person, I have no idea what you're doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, if your problem is to detect if localStorage is available, you can do somethinglike

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("key",value);
} else {
    // localStorage is not available
}
```

Comment: that's not what I meant. I want to store some html how can do that?

Comment: Please reconsider your downvote, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having that "storage" action, make it an onclick or something different because it seems like you are attempting to store something rather than have an event trigger as soon as something is stored to localStorage.

Comment: I see in forms in the end they have the onclick event to store everything. But here I don't have a form or anything. But as you said I can store the  html everytime the html of the element changes. But that would too much code.

Comment: Replace "storage" with "change" in your code, I think this is what you're asking for.

Comment: The change event is only triggered for changes to form control elements, not to arbitrary DOM elements.

Comment: Without context and without a desired time for the localStorage to fire, this is harder to advise.